# Replace Plus sign in string php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have string `Adult-Cruise+Lunch_label` i want to remove + sign from the string.
I have used `preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_option->getTitle())` to remove space from the string. 
how can i add code to remove + sign from the string.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What's the bigger picture? What's `$_option`? and what's `getTitle()`? Will there be any other characters that might appear in this string that you want removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_replace('/[\s\+]/', '', $_option->getTitle());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
preg_replace(/[+]/, "", $_option->getTitle());
```

This will remove only the plus sign from the string.

Answer (score 0):

You canu remove + sign using javascript replace function.

var string = "Adult-Cruise+Lunch_label";
string = string.replace('+','%2B');

I think it may be work.